# Google App Engine deployment failing because requirements.txt file can't be found in workspace

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, gcloud

Has anybody received a 'Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/workspace/requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies\r"' error when trying to deploy a python37 app to Google App Engine?

I am trying to deploy my web app using the python 37 standard runtime, and get the following build error:

```
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/workspace/requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies\r"
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
```

I have double checked the the requirements.txt file is located in the same directory as the main.py script, and it seems as though the requirements.txt file is read in on deployment based on what the logs are saying but then fails to find the file in the workspace.

I am deploying from a virtual env and have made sure to run the 'pip install -r requirements.txt' command within the virtual env, but it still gives the same error in the logs when I deploy. Below is a copy of the contents of the app.yaml file and a portion of the logs.

app.yaml file

```
runtime: python37

instance_class: B8
basic_scaling:
   max_instances: 1
   idle_timeout: 1m

handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: auto
```

Logs:

```
Step #1 - "builder": # This requirements file lists all third-party 
dependencies for this project.
Step #1 - "builder": #
Step #1 - "builder": # Run 'pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/' to     
install these dependencies
Step #1 - "builder": # in `lib/` subdirectory.
Step #1 - "builder": #
Step #1 - "builder": # Note: The `lib` directory is added to `sys.path` by `appengine_config.py`.
Step #1 - "builder": flask==1.0.2
Step #1 - "builder": flask-restful==0.3.6
Step #1 - "builder": firebase-admin==2.14.0
Step #1 - "builder": pandas==0.23.4
Step #1 - "builder": datetime==4.3
Step #1 - "builder": google.auth==1.6.2
Step #1 - "builder": google.cloud==0.34.0
Step #1 - "builder": google-cloud-pubsub==0.39.0
Step #1 - "builder": dfply==0.3.3
Step #1 - "builder": requests==2.21.0
Step #1 - "builder": gunicorn
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO found recursive python requirements file: requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies
Step #1 - "builder": INFO checking_cached_requirements.txt_layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder": exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 114, in Build
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 116, in BuildLayer
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/single_layer_image.py", line 60, in GetCacheKey
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 107, in GetCacheKeyRaw
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_util.py", line 168, in descriptor_parser
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/context.py", line 80, in GetFile
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/workspace/requirements.txt -t lib/' to install these dependencies\r"
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
```

Comment: I used the same app.yaml configuration and the packages specified in the logs, but was unable to reproduce the issue - the GAE app deployed fine for me. Are you deploying with gcloud app deploy without any flags? Are all the files (app.yaml, main.py and requirements.txt) contained in the same directory? Are you deploying from this directory?

Comment: Please see answer below @Maxim. Thanks for trying to figure it out

Comment: Thank you for the update, and for providing an answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a while for me to figure out but the reason why the requirements.txt file could not be found in the work-space was due to having headers in the .txt file commented out, but of course it's not a python script so the comments were preventing the file from being read correctly.

As soon as I removed any comments and kept only package names it deployed correctly.

Comment: This is a bug in App Engine, it is mis-parsing the comment as a recursive dependency. I've filed an issue internally, thanks for catching this!